# Extracting information from a field using Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I need to extract specific information from a field using Visual Studio 2005.  I need only the 'partNumber' and the 'serialNumber' from this field;

> BeginGroup:databasecurrentFifos=0maximumFifos=34369maximumSpace=6291456percentUsed=7totalFixedSpace=123156totalIndexSpace=77182totalRowCount=2533totalRowSpace=139024totalTableSpace=339362uncollectedFifos=0usedSpace=478386EndGroup:databaseBeginGroup:networkDNS_ServerIP=NoneDNS_DomainName=NoneFTP_Enabled=falseEndGroup:networkBeginGroup:hardwareBeginGroup:biometricsEndGroup:biometricsBeginGroup:mSystemformat=7101processorType=859chipId=CFEndGroup:mSystemBeginGroup:barcodesBarcode_attached=noSymbologies=code3of9
>   i2of5
>   code128Remote_Barcode_attached=noEndGroup:barcodesBeginGroup:boardrevision=REV
>   Aversion=415partNumber=8602800-503serialNumber=JC117590EndGroup:boardBeginGroup:magneticstrackNum=noEndGroup:magneticsBeginGroup:memorySDRAM=134217728BeginGroup:flashDisksflashDisk0=1018773504flashDisk1=0numOfFlashDisks=1EndGroup:flashDisksEndGroup:memoryBeginGroup:peripheralsmodem=noneWand_attached=noEndGroup:peripheralsBeginGroup:keypadKeypad_Type=NumericEndGroup:keypadBeginGroup:proximityReadersProximityReader_attached=noProxReaderFormat1=Default
>   26 Bit
>   FormatProximityReader_NumRecords=2RemoteProx_attached=noRemoteProxFormat1=Default
>   26 Bit
>   FormatRemoteProx_NumRecords=2EndGroup:proximityReadersEndGroup:hardwareBeginGroup:softwarerelease=03.00.07.006
>
> HTMLClientVersion=5708model=Kronos-4500OSversion=5708bootVersion=5708appVersion=5708dbSchema=5708Font_Information=Default
>   Latin fonts. EndGroup:software

Comment: What programming language are you using? Where is the data stored?

Comment: SQL.  I'm getting the information from our time and attendance program.  Hopefully this helps...I'm not much of a technical person.

Comment: You will have to be more specific otherwise you won't be able to get much help here. SQL as in running query/stored procedure in SQL Server? Or SQL simple retrieves data and it is used in VB.NET/C# program?

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes VB.NET is used and also assumes that structure of the source string doesn't change.

```
'Variable to hold source data
Dim sSource As String 

'*** perform code here to load source (from DB etc.) ***

'separator array (change this as needed if sructure of the source sting changes)
Dim sSep As String() = {"partNumber=", "serialNumber=", "EndGroup:boardBeginGroup:magnetic"}

'split the source into Array
Dim asSplit As String() = sSource.Split(sSep, StringSplitOptions.None)

'get Part Number
Dim sPartNumber As String = asSplit(1)

'get Serial Number
Dim sSerialNumber As String = asSplit(2)
```

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2005 to write reports (rather than using Crystal) and trying to figure out how to use a function to parse out only the partNumber and serialNumber.  I really don't understand using Dim or entering the information you gave.  Sorry I'm just not very technical.

Comment: I am sorry but this is a programmers Q&A board you have to have at least basic knowledge of the language you're using.